# Setting environment variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I use Webstorm as javascript ide and i have set an environment variable via configuration;

```
var pass = process.env.pass;
//console.log(pass);

if (userName == 'admin' && password == pass) {
          //do something    
        }
```

If i run the script file it works fine without any problem and i can see the password in console, but when i run the index.html page, it does not load the page properly and when i delete `var pass = process.env.pass;` and use a hardcoded password, it loads the page without any problem.

I'm new to javascript and am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: "when i run the index.html page" what exactly does that entail? your environment variables are server side, not client side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`process.env`is Node.js construct. 
`index.html` is static webpage displayed in browser, hence there is no notion of environment variables.

How are you using javascript code? As a Node module or as browser script?

Comment: No i dont use node modules, i make a static webpage. Is there any way to use an environment variable or similar thing in a static weppage?

Comment: @AdamJungen you shouldn't use them "in a static webpage", you set them server side, and then your backend will send the relevant data to your front end

Comment: @AdamJungen two words: global variable! :)

Comment: @Daniel Lizik, i wanted to hide the variables. Thanx